# Simplify matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, computation, simplification

I'm making some matrix computation in matlab. What looks strange (to me) is that I get results like

```
(8700286382685973*cos(q5)*sin(q4))/9007199254740992 + sin(q5)*((43220913799951902644522757965203*cos(q4))/730750818665451459101842416358141509827966271488 - 291404338770025/1125899906842624)
```

but matlab does not simplify the result. I already tried to use functions like `simplify`, `simple`,`fix` but none of them gave the desired result.

Any suggestion on what function should I use?

Comment: How do you know that it could be simpler?  Besides "I think so"?

Comment: Because `43220913799951902644522757965203/730750818665451459101842416358141509827966271488` is almost 0.

Comment: OK, so you're left with the first term.  Those constants look suspicious to me, too.  How did you arrive at this result?  What's the back story?

Comment: I followed the Denavit-Hartember convention to compute the direct kinematic of a manipulator. However I don't think this is relevant...Even putting those value by hand I expected matlab to simplify the result.

Comment: But ALMOST zero is not truly zero, any more than almost pregnant is actually pregnant. This is a symbolic solution. If you wish a numerical answer, then vpa can help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lucas suggested, you can use vpa and digits in matlab, for example if the expression above is A (sym) then:

```
 vpa(A,3) % digits is set to 3

 ans = 

  0.966*cos(q5)*sin(q4) + sin(q5)*(5.91e-17*cos(q4) - 0.259)
```

And then you can either see the numbers for themselves and chop them, or use something like:

```
 function result = significant(x, n)
 % significant(x, n) rounds number x to n number of significant figures

 s = floor(log10(abs(x)));
 shift = 10^(n-1);
 mant = round(x*shift/(10^s)) / shift;
 result = mant * 10^s;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplify does only "exact" manipulations. What you need is a command that kills small terms in your expression. In Mathematica "Chop" takes care of that. Try to google it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing one of these commands before your evaluation:

```
format longe
format shorte
```